# Convert python file with mediapipe into .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, mediapipe

I have created a virtual mouse (uses opencv & mediapipe to track your hand and apply movement to the mouse). The problem is that upon running the exe I get an error, because it can no longer access the mediapipe files.

Specifically, it couldn't access two, both found in C:\Users\hchap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions

Anybody know how to include mediapipe's dependencies (the files) into an exe?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put all these files together, you gonna have to tell  `PyInstaller` to include them, lets do that by creating a `spec` file.

First we generate it

```
pyinstaller --name=my_script my_script.py
```

then we modify our `my_script.spec` so that for the `a = Analysis()` we have something like the code below, modify the paths as needed.

```
a = Analysis(['my_script.py'],
             pathex=['path\\to\\your\\script'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                 ('C:\\Users\\hchap\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Lib\\site-packages\\mediapipe\\python\\solutions\\*.*', 'mediapipe\\python\\solutions'),
                 # Add any other necessary directories here.
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

then we can rebuild our application with our `spec` file

```
pyinstaller my_script.spec
```

Now the resulting executable have the necessary `MediaPipe` files bundled with it.